# Python - How to show dictionary values from two keys side by side in django template for all values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, django-views, django-templates

Say I have the following dictionary in my django views:

```
dict_lyrics = {'question': ['word1', 'word2'], 'answer': ['word3', 'word4']}
```

Now in my template I want to display this as:

word1 - word3 
word2 - word4

(It is already in the right order.)

But I can't get it right. How can I get the first value from the one key and the first value from the second key and so on? I've googled endlessly and am going in circles.

If I iterate like this:

```
{% for key, value in dict_lyrics.items %}
    <tr>
        <td> Key: {{ key }} </td>
        <td> Value: {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

...I get all the values from the one key and then all the values from the other key. How can I show them side by side, or is it better to change my dictionary?

My views:

```
z = []
dict_lyrics = {'question': [], 'answer': []}
for word in user_word:
    x = lyrics_list_clean.index(word)
    y = user_word.index(word)
    flash = Flashcard.objects.get(owner=self.request.user, question=word)
    z.append(flash.answer)
    dict_lyrics['question'].append(lyrics_list_clean[x])
    dict_lyrics['answer'].append(z[y])
    context['question'] = dict_lyrics['question']
    context['answer'] = dict_lyrics['answer']
    context['dict_lyrics'] = dict_lyrics
```

Thank you in advance for any advice / help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to my views:

```
context['combined'] = list(zip(dict_lyrics['question'], dict_lyrics['answer']))
```

And then using this in the template:

```
{% for i, j in combined %}
    {{ i }} -- {{ j }}
{% endfor %}
```

Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question and how dict_lyrics is going, if you want to show for question 0 the answer 0 and for question 1 the answer 1, in this form:

```
word1 - word3
word2 - word4
```

you could do like this:

```
answers = [v for subl in li.values() for v in subl]
frist_qa = answers[0::2]
second_qa = answers[1::2]
print(f"{' '.join(first_qa)}")
print(f"{' '.join(second_qa)}")
```

Where `first_qa` holds `['word1', 'word3']` and `second_qa` holds `['word2', 'word4']`

In a more general way, with, for example, this dict_lyrics `dict_lyrics = {'question': ['word1', 'word2', 'wordX'], 'answer': ['word3', 'word4', 'wordY']}`

and assuming that `len(dict_lyrics["question"]) == len(dict_lyrics["answer"])`

```
for i in range(len(li["question"])):
    print(f"{li['question'][i]} {li['answer'][i]}")
```

should do the trick:

```
word1 word3
word2 word4
wordX wordY
```

**Edit**: After comment, i guess that you are looking for some kind of HTML output. I'd change de loop you show in your question like this:

```
{% for i in range(len(li["question"])): %}
    <tr>
        <td> Key: {{ li['question'][i] }} </td>
        <td> Value: {{ li['answer'][i] }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would I render it in my template (instead of printing)?

Comment: I've edited my comment to show some sort of HTML output. Is that what you need?